# Call function every 10 seconds while being in a loop

Tags: php, sockets, loops, delay

Basically, I have a socket and a while loop to constantly get it's data, like this:

```
while (TRUE)
{ 
    $read = fgets($fp); //get data
    if (preg_match("/:(\S+)!\S+@\S+ JOIN (#\S+)/i", $read, $match)) { user_joined($match[1],    $match[2]); } //JOIN
    if (preg_match("/:(\S+)!\S+@\S+ PART (#\S+)/i", $read, $match)) { user_parted($match[1], $match[2]); } //PART
    if (preg_match("/:(\S+)!\S+@\S+ PRIVMSG (#\S+) :(.*)/i", $read, $match)) { inc_message($match[1], $match[2], $match[3]); } //MESSAGE
    if (preg_match("/:jtv!jtv@\S+ PRIVMSG $nick :(\S+)/i", $read, $match)){jtv_error($match[1]);} //JTV WARNING
    if (preg_match("/PING :.*/i", $read, $match)) { fwrite($fp, "PONG :$match[1]\r\n"); } //respond to server
}
```

Now, I also want to execute a function every 10 seconds to reset some vars. How can I do this without really blocking the loop? If it's blocked for like 0.1 seconds I don't mind.

Comment: I'm curious about the CPU usage with such a code

Comment: Depends on how long the function takes to return.

Comment: @AbraCadaver are you sure of this ? For me, no matter what code is inside this loop, it will be 100% since there's no sleep function used here... But I might be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, that was directed at OP about not blocking the loop for long.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I just want to call a void function which resets some variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP performs quite badly when trying to do realtime stuff. What you could do is get the time before the beginning of the loop, wait a bit after your code has executed (to prevent huge CPU load) and get the time after that :

```
$timeCursor = microtime(true);

while (TRUE)
{ 
    $read = fgets($fp); //get data
    if (preg_match("/:(\S+)!\S+@\S+ JOIN (#\S+)/i", $read, $match)) { user_joined($match[1],    $match[2]); } //JOIN
    if (preg_match("/:(\S+)!\S+@\S+ PART (#\S+)/i", $read, $match)) { user_parted($match[1], $match[2]); } //PART
    if (preg_match("/:(\S+)!\S+@\S+ PRIVMSG (#\S+) :(.*)/i", $read, $match)) { inc_message($match[1], $match[2], $match[3]); } //MESSAGE
    if (preg_match("/:jtv!jtv@\S+ PRIVMSG $nick :(\S+)/i", $read, $match)){jtv_error($match[1]);} //JTV WARNING
    if (preg_match("/PING :.*/i", $read, $match)) { fwrite($fp, "PONG :$match[1]\r\n"); } //respond to server

    usleep(50000); // do nothing for 50 ms

    $currentTime = microtime(true);
    if ($timeCursor + 10 <= $currentTime) {
        $timeCursor = $currentTime;
        // here you can call a function every 10s
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came back to this late but you might also just add something like this to your loop:

```
if(time() % 10 === 0) { /* your_func(); */ }
```